# myfaces EL support disabled?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, el, myfaces

I am starter in JSF2.0.
I am using MyFaces.
My little tutorial apps are ok, but I noticed in the logs of MyFaces the following:

> org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications
>   isUnifiedELAvailable INFO: MyFaces
>   Unified EL support disabled

I am not sure what does this actually mean, and also how I could enable it if want to? Via the web.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyFaces 2 will take advantage of [JSP EL 2.2 features](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245) if they are available; I'm guessing your container provides JSP 2.1.

Comment: I am using Tomcat 6. Where does tomcat define this?In the release notes?

Comment: @user384706 - Tomcat 6 is a JSP 2.1 container (see the Reference section of the docs); JSR 245 defines both 2.1 and 2.2 (see the 2009 maintenance release). `isUnifiedELAvailable` looks for the presence of a method that is only present in 2.2; if not, the calling code falls back to some other mechanism. https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/myfaces/core/tags/2_0_0/impl/src/main/java/org/apache/myfaces/util/ExternalSpecifications.java

Comment: in the READ ME link it mentions `apache-tomcat-[version]-fulldocs.tar.gz` but it is not there in the downloads section

Comment: You can download files here: http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/ In any case, the docs will probably already be in the `webapps/docs` directory of your Tomcat install.